# How do I create a keyboard key?

Tags: support

I see keyboard keys on this question
[Deleting an Entire Line Moving Forward Shortcut](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/121821/deleting-an-entire-line-moving-forward-shortcut)
But there's no shortcut on how to make them?

Comment: Any chance this can be built-in the question field? Like code block?

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard keys can be created using `<kbd>` tags.

Example: <kbd>⌘</kbd>

For the key symbols, see
[Put the ⌃⌥⇧⌘⎋⏏⌫↑⇡↖⇞⇥ characters somewhere for people to copy/paste](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/683/put-the-characters-somewhere-for-people-to-copy-paste)